# Group a List of Data by Date

Tags: c#

I have a List that contains data from various dates. I would like to create a sub list of data that only contains information from a certain interval such as today all the way back to 6 months ago.

```
var results = Bean.GroupBy(dc => new {dc.serviceType, dc.periodType}).Select( WHAT GOES HERE?)
```

period is the name of the interval of time in my list

I want something like:      period between Date1 and Date2

Thanks

Comment: You should probably look for Where extension. Something like var x = Bean.Where(s => s.Date < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10) && s.Date > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-100));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

`var results = Bean.Where(x => x.period > Date1 && x.period < Date2).GroupBy(dc => new {dc.serviceType, dc.periodType})`